# Use "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" (6.0.x) in base library project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, routes, nuget, .net-6.0

My goal is a base library that will be used by multiple other service APIs. In .NET 6, your web apps that use `SDK="Microsoft.NET.SDK.Web"` require an 'entry point' (i.e. static main method, or Program.cs). A base library doesn't need an entry point, so I instead set the `SDK="Microsoft.NET.SDK"`.

Next, I need access to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" (6.0.x). NuGet only has up to version 2.x.x. Version 6.x.x seems to only be available as part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref package. However, it states on nuget that this is not for direct package references.

I can't change my SDK because my library needs an entry point, and I can't get a version of Routing that matches .NET 6.

How do I get access to Routing in a base library?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

You can add a framework reference, which is like a package reference except you can specify the web framework.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I am stuck at exactly the same problem but targeting net7 is this not possible anymore? I added the ItemGroup to my csproj but i have no access to IEndpointRouteBuilder.